# Adding filenames from a directory to a char* array. c++

Tags: c++, arrays, windows, file

I ame trying to get filenames from a directory and put it in a char* array for latter use. But this dont seem to work the way i want to. When printing it only showes the last filename on all spots.

So my question howe can i add the file names in every spot inside the char*[]?

```
/*Placed outside*/
int i = 0;
char* Files[20] = {};
/*Placed outside*/

while (handle != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
    char buffer[4100];
    sprintf_s(buffer, "%ls", search_data.cFileName);
    Files[i] = buffer;
    i++;
    if (FindNextFile(handle, &search_data) == FALSE)


  /*Printing I use ImGui*/
 #define IM_ARRAYSIZE(_ARR)  ((int)(sizeof(_ARR)/sizeof(*_ARR)))
static int listbox_item_current = 1;
ImGui::ListBox("", &listbox_item_current, Files, i, 4);
```

Comment: Where is FindNextFile?

Comment: `Files[i] = buffer;` copies the address of a temporary. If you don't understand what it implies, don't use C-style char arrays and arrays of `char*`; use `std::string`.

Comment: partial code, impossible to help

Comment: Better to `memcpy()` `buffer` into `Files[i]`

Comment: Just use `std::string`

Comment: `std::string` has method `c_str` which returns NULL-terminated `char*`

Comment: The reason why I use char* instead of std::string is because i use Imgui and that doesent support std::string

Comment: use std::vector or std::array avoid C style arrays the same as you avoid malloc/free and new/delete.

Comment: @ILIkeStackOverFLowWhanIgetHelp  Imgui not supporting std::string or std::wstring doesn't prevent your code from using them.

Comment: @MichaëlRoy Howe can i than print it? 

Sins it is a const char* const* items.

Comment: @ILIkeStackOverFLowWhanIgetHelp  Create a temporary list of string pointers for the call.  Or use the Imgui function that adds items one by one.

Comment: @MichaëlRoy ok, i think i understend it now :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use C++ standard filesystem, but for that I guess you would need C++17 (or atleast VS15), not really sure.

You would have to include:

```
#include <experimental/filesystem>
#include <filesystem>
using namespace std::experimental::filesystem::v1;
```

Using it should be simple:

```
int i = 0;
const char * directoryToSearch = "C:\etc\etc";
for (const auto & file : directory_iterator(directoryToSearch)) {
    files[i] = new char[file.path().stem().string().length() + 1];
    strcpy(files[i], file.path().stem().string().c_str());
    ++i;
}
```

Indeed, you should clean up the array after you're done using it. Don't forget, not many compilers support this at the moment.

Comment: Thanks :D This solved my problem :D
+shorted down the code

Answer (score 0):

*When printing it only shows the last filename on all spots.* That is just normal: you store the filename on each iteration in the same buffer and just copy the address of the buffer into your array. Unrelated to the question, as `buffer` is an automatic variable declared inside a loop (block scoped), using it outside of the loop is Undefined Behaviour, so you end with an array of *dangling* pointers.

The correct way would be to either use a 2D-array `char Files[MAX_PATH][20];` and store a file name in each slot, or use dynamic memory allocate by `new` (or malloc at a lower level). For the second option, you can do it *by hand*, allocating memory for each file name - and remember to free anything at the end, or you can let the standard library manage it for you by using:

```
std::vector<std::string> Files;
...
while(...) {
    ...
    File.push_back(search_data.cFileName);
```

Dear ImGui provides a `ListBox`ctor that allows to pass an opaque data storage along with an extractor, and it can be used here:

```
bool string_vector_items_getter(void* data, int idx, const char** out_text) {
    std::vector<std::string> *v = reinterpret_cast<std::vector<std::string> >(data);
    if (idx < 0 || idx >= v.size()) return false;
    *out_text = v[idx].c_str();
    return true;
}
```

and then:

```
ImGui::ListBox("", &listbox_item_current, &string_vector_items_getter, &Files, i, 4);
```

(beware: untested code!)